# Instantiate superclass before calling factory method

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiple-inheritance

I'm trying to initialize a superclass before calling the subclass. Here is an example of what I'm trying to do:

```
class AbstractSourceParser(object):

    def __init__(self, filepath):

        self.source_type = get_type_from_filepath(filepath)

    @staticmethod
    def factory(source_type):

        source_type = source_type.upper() if source_type else None

        if source_type == SourceType.CSV.upper():
            return CSVSourceParser() 

class CSVSourceParser(AbstractSourceParser):
    ...
```

And then I want to be able to call it like this:

```
parser = AbstractSourceParser("/tmp/file.csv").factory(self.type)
```

I think what I'm writing above doesn't make sense in code, but basically I want to retrieve the factory method 'after' passing in some data to the super class. How would this be done?

Currently, what I'm doing is the following, which I think is quite ugly (if not possibly incorrect) --

```
>>> _parser = AbstractSourceParser("/tmp/file.csv")
>>> parser = _parser.factory(_parser.source_type)
```

Comment: Could you please clarify your question a bit? You mention a super class, but your example shows now class inheritance. And the bit at the bottom with `AbstractSourceParser`, how does that fit in? Thanks!

Comment: @NikolasStevenson-Molnar thanks for the feedback, I've updated it a bit...

Answer (score 0):

You could make `factory()` a regular instance method, and let it do the work:

```
class AbstractSourceParser(object):
    def __init__(self, filepath):
        self.source_type = get_type_from_filepath(filepath)

    def factory(self, source_type=None):
        if source_type is None:
            source_type = self.source_type

        source_type = source_type.upper() if source_type else None

        if source_type == SourceType.CSV.upper():
            return CSVSourceParser()
```

So that if you want the source type defined in the parent constructor, you can call `factory()` with no arguments. But you can still provide a different `source_type` if you want.

Does that get at what you're asking?

Comment: thanks for this -- but to make it a regular instance method wouldn't have to have it call `self` in the constructor?

Comment: I think you mean that the function needs a `self` arg? In that case, yes: good catch! I will update.